# How can I make a more generic isEmpty() function in Dart?

Tags: generics, dart, types, dynamic-typing

I have the following utility function for checking if a `String` variable is empty or null:

```
bool isEmpty(String s){
  return (s??'').isEmpty;
}
```

Now I want to make a similar function for `Iterable`s. The implementation is trivial:

```
bool isEmpty(Iterable i){
  return (i??[]).isEmpty;
}
```

But now I have to either name the two functions differently, or somehow merge them into one. Here's where I run into trouble.

I can make the variable `dynamic`:

```
bool isEmpty(dynamic x){
  if( x is String) return (x??'').isEmpty;
  if( x is Iterable) return (x??[]).isEmpty;
  throw UnimplementedError('isEmpty() is not defined for the type ${x.runtimeType}');
}
```

but then x will be of type `Null` if I pass `String s = null` or `Set s = null`. What if in the future I want to treat `null` differently for `Iterable` and `String`?

I could make the function generic:

```
bool isEmpty<T>(T x){
  if( T == String) return ((x as String)??'').isEmpty;
  if( T == Iterable) return ((x as Iterable)??[]).isEmpty;
  throw UnimplementedError('isEmpty() is not defined for the type $T');
}
```

but now it will throw an exception if I pass a `List`, `Set` or anything else that is a *subtype* of `Iterable`, but not an *actual* `Iterable`.

How can I make one single `isEmpty()` function that works exactly as the two separate ones that accept `String` and `Iterable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make extensions. Like these:

```
extension StringExt on String {
  bool isNullOrEmpty() => this == null || this.isEmpty;
}

extension IterableExt<T> on Iterable<T> {
  bool isNullOrEmpty() => this == null || this.isEmpty;
}
```

I've renamed `isEmpty` to `isNullOrEmpty` due to name conflicts (`String.isEmpty, Iterable<T>.isEmpty`...).

Comment: This works! I was surprised to see that calling `x.isNullOrEmpty` on `List x = null;` works and returns `true`, but it does indeed.